# Eclipse Not Opening. Worked fine yesterday. Not opening today. Getting error log message

Tags: java, eclipse

Here's the error log that it directed me to. I'm very new to coding and have no idea what it's asking me to fix. I tried to look it up but the few solutions I could find didnt't help. I changed the environment variable HOME to %USERPROFILE% but I don't think that was the right thing to do. Please help!

I've tried re-installing Eclipse but it still won't work.

---

```
   !SESSION 2017-03-28 10:56:50.318 -----------------------------------------------
    eclipse.buildId=4.6.2.M20161124-1400
    java.version=1.8.0_112
    java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
    BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_CA
    Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product C:\Users\ssfro\OneDrive\Fanshawe\INFO-1150 Programming\workspace\School     Projects\src\Spencer_Frost_INFO1150_Project.java
    Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product C:\Users\ssfro\OneDrive\Fanshawe\INFO-1150 Programming\workspace\School Projects\src\Spencer_Frost_INFO1150_Project.java

    !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2017-03-28 10:56:52.694
    !MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-03-28 10:56:52.842
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.resources (84).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is described here, too: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/156204/

You could also try this:
rename your current workspace folder. Open eclipse again and create an new one. Then either try to load your old one from the menu or try to put your project folders into the new workspace via your OS-filemanager (explorer / finder / whatever). Then refresh the workspace.

Hope this helped. Googeling your error sometimes does wonders, too...

Comment: Thank you!!! This fixed it! I googled it and asked my professor but couldn't find the answer.